# How to fix this React useEffect error " Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

**I have 2 dashboard 1 for user and other admin and have home button on nav which redirects to userdashboard**
**Admin user have role defined as admin on them**

Here i am using useEffect hook to redirect admin to admindashboard if he clicks home button,

```
export default function Dashboard() {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const role = user.user_info.roles;
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (role === "admin") {
      history.push("/admin-dashboard");
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Banner />
      <Row1 />
      <Row2 />
      <Row3 />
      <Row4 />
      <Row5 />
      <Row6 />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Banner n each row are mapping videos

```
export default function Row1() {
  const history = useHistory();

  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const data = await getAllVideosTopRated();
      setVideos(data);
    };

    getData();
  }, []);

  const handleClick = (id) => {
    history.push(`/videoplayer/${id}`);
  };

  const responsive = {
    desktop: {
      breakpoint: { max: 3000, min: 1024 },
      items: 5,
      slidesToSlide: 3,
    },
    laptop: {
      breakpoint: { max: 1024, min: 768 },
      items: 3,
      slidesToSlide: 2, // optional, default to 1.
    },
    tablet: {
      breakpoint: { max: 768, min: 464 },
      items: 2,
    },
    mobile: {
      breakpoint: { max: 464, min: 330 },
      items: 1,
    },
    mobileSmall: {
      breakpoint: { max: 320, min: 0 },
      items: 1,
      slidesToSlide: 1, // optional, default to 1.
    },
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Container maxWidth="xl" className="row">
        <h2>Top Rated</h2>
        {videos !== null && videos.length ? (
          <Carousel responsive={responsive} swipeable={true}>
            {videos.map((item) => (
              <div className="row_thumbnails" key={item.id}>
                <img
                  onClick={() => handleClick(item.id)}
                  className="row_thumbnail"
                  src={item.thumbnail}
                  alt={item.title}
                />
              </div>
            ))}
          </Carousel>
        ) : (
          <Loader />
        )}
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

This is getAllvideos api call

```
let data = null;

export const getAllVideos = async () => {
  await axios
    .post(`${apis.all}`)
    .then((res) => {
      data = res.data;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  return data;
};
```

It redirects as expected but i get this above mentioned error with each row in browser console

Comment: (1) It's right in the text, it's only a warning, and (2) Where are you enqueueing any state updates? Is this a complete code example?

Comment: What inside your `Banner` and what wrap around your `Dashboard`?

Comment: Hey @DrewReese, We've met so many times, Boss!. Just want to say "Hi"

Comment: just error in browser console log other things r fine it goes on my admin dashboard

Comment: Are any of these children components enqueueing state updates when they mount that resolve *after* this parent `Dashboard` component unmounts? What are they doing on component mount?

Comment: For eg  like this it gives 7 error in brower console logs  mentioning each row  "Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    at Row3 
    at Dashboard"

Comment: I see, so these row components are definitely relevant code and should be included in your question/issue.

Comment: banner and each row is mapping list of videos

Comment: i posted row 1 u can see now

Comment: Hii @RyanLe learning is difficult task xD

Comment: Hey, I posted an answer below, see if it helps. Anw, Drew ignored me :(

Comment: Can you now share what `getAllVideosTopRated` is doing? Sounds like it is doing an asynchronous fetch. @RyanLe Sorry, I didn't intentionally ignore you, just didn't respond yet. ‍♂️ Yes, we seem to be on a similar schedule.

Answer (score 1):

## **You have a `setState` which possibly run after the `history.push`**

### **Quick fix:**

Remove the useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (role === "admin") {
    history.push("/admin-dashboard");
  }
}, []);
```

**TO:**

```
if (role === "admin") {
    history.push("/admin-dashboard");
}
```

By doing this, your `Row(n)` won't have a chance to render, so API won't start to fetch.

---

### **Explanation:**

In this block:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async () => {
    const data = await getAllVideosTopRated();
    setVideos(data);
  };

  getData();
}, []);
```

You are `await` for `getAllVideosTopRated` to be finished then `setVideos(data)`, but the `history.push` in the `Dashboard` was fired first, then your async function still going on and `setState` while your component is already unmounted.

**That is why you see the error with the same meaning**

Comment: i tried ur solution removed useEffect it goes on admin dashboard like previously but console error is changed now to    "Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
    at Dashboard"

Comment: It's another problem, mate. Might be related to your `admin-dashboard` component. You could raise another question about that.

Comment: Anyway, that error is occur when you are trying to change state when the component has not finished render yet.

Comment: i just used window.location.replace instead of history.push it worked with no errors in console. Does  window.location.replace doesnt let dashboard to render futher if role is admin ?

Comment: That's a bit strange to me. Sorry I've no clue about that behaviour without looking at the whole context.

Comment: @chaitu605 Using `window.location.replace` will reload your app, so any pending state updates are wiped out (*why the warning goes away*). So is any state you had in memory until it's reinitialized/fetched.

Comment: ohh i see.  Posted getAllVideos api call i m using within rows all have similar codes according to thier genre